Clicking Enter button in android hits topmost Button element
I have an app written using Jetpack Compose. When I hit "Enter" button on a keyboard, it hits the first Button() element on a current screen. How do I prevent this behaviour?
Don't know if there's a reason to provide any source code, as it works with any Button() element or IconButton() that is first on the form in the code.

Sometimes, Jetpack Compose doesn't immediately guess the correct next item, especially when complex parent Composables come into play.
Some composables are focusable by design, such as a Button or a composable with a clickable modifier attached to it.
This is the official documentation of Change focus behavior.
In the documentation, it is mentioned how to Make a Composable Focusable and Make a Composable Unfocusable.

Is there a good way to apply Modifier.focusProperties { canFocus = false } to all Button() elements in project?
